# Interchange of finite summation and definite integration

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Since I have no or less knowledge in mathematics, may anybody help me with proof whether the summation and integration can be interchanged in the following situation?
$$
\sum_{m=-N}^{N}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{d\psi}{2\pi i} \frac{e^{i\psi}}{\psi + i\:m^2}
$$
A lot of thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming each improper integral converges,  yes.  If they don't converge independently, no.

Comment: @Alan Thanks a lot. It was a part of my work if I ever put the work in the public domain I will certainly acknowledge you.